# Sort and rearrange array elements

Tags: php, sorting

```
$people = array(
    array('id' => 12345,'first_name' => 'Joe1','date' => '02/06/2011'),
    array('id' => 12346,'first_name' => 'Joe','date' => '01/27/2011'),
    array('id' => 12347,'first_name' => 'rah','date' => '01/22/2011'),
    array('id' => 12348,'first_name' => 'sar','date' => '02/21/2011'),
    array('id' => 12349,'first_name' => 'raj','date' => '04/18/2011'),
    array('id' => 12350,'first_name' => 'viv','date' => '01/31/2011'),
);
```

I want this array elements to sort by date and then rearrange the array elements according to the ascending order of date in php
say the after process should look like this below on ,

```
var_export($people); 
//answer

array(
  array('id' => 12347, 'first_name' => 'rah', 'date' => '01/22/2011'),
  array('id' => 12346, 'first_name' => 'Joe', 'date' => '01/27/2011'),
  array('id' => 12350, 'first_name' => 'viv', 'date' => '01/31/2011'),
  array('id' => 12345, 'first_name' => 'Joe1', 'date' => '02/06/2011'),
  array('id' => 12348, 'first_name' => 'sar', 'date' => '02/21/2011'),
  array('id' => 12349, 'first_name' => 'raj', 'date' => '04/18/2011')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to do it manually (by means of [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)):

```
function mdy2ymd($date) {
        $parts = explode('/', $date);
        return $parts[2] . $parts[0] . $parts[1]; // YYYYMMDD
}

function sortByDate($a, $b) {
        return mdy2ymd($a['date']) - mdy2ymd($b['date']);
}

usort($people, 'sortByDate');
```

([Demo](http://www.ideone.com/VpLvF))

`sortByDate()` is the comparison function and `mdy2ymd()` is just a helper to make timestamps on the form `MM/DD/YYYY` comparable.

Comment: thanks, it worked for me.. great job 'jensgram' have a great day

Answer (score 0):

See [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) example #3